# Why does Windows chkdsk take longer to check user data than free space?

Tags: windows, usb-3, chkdsk

I'm currently checking some 2nd hand 2.5" disks connected via a USB-3 disk enclosure. The first check is to copy files onto the disk to fill it. The next is to use **chkdsk /r**. On a 500GB SATA-3 disk, **chkdsk /r** on an empty just-formatted disk has an ETA of just over an hour. However, if I chkdsk a full disk, the ETA is much longer, like 70+ hours.

Why this difference? Does chkdsk carry out a deeper check of used disk space compared to free space?

Comment: How confident are you in that the disk enclosure is actually connected at USB 3.2 Gen 1 speeds instead of USB 2.0 speeds.

Comment: I use UsbTreeView and CrystalDiskInfo. It's connected at USB 3.0 SuperSpeed. My motherboard/enclosure is a few years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the chkdsk /r has to a number of checks on each file, and empty sector it just checks if its readable and then moves on.

Cross links, name violations, security descriptors, directory structures and more are check for actual files.  It check the whole MFT (Master File Table) for each and every file.

None of these structures exist for unused space.

```
Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  416256 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 12.94 seconds.
  4854 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 0.00 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 1.05 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  189 reparse records processed.
  617000 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 21.18 seconds.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 1.79 seconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 2.78 milliseconds.
  189 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 2.53 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 24.51 milliseconds.
  100373 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 0.29 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  39161816 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
 Phase duration (USN journal verification): 202.13 milliseconds.
```

From this list we can gather this info

> Examining basic file system structure ...

> File record verification

> Orphan file record recovery

> Bad file record checking reparse records processed.

> Index verification unindexed files scanned.

> Orphan reconnection unindexed files recovered to lost and found.

> Reparse point and Object ID verification

> Examining security descriptors ...

> Data attribute verification verifying Usn Journal...

Answer (score 2):

[chkdsk documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk?tabs=event-viewer) :

> **/r**
>
> Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information. The disk must
> be locked. **/r includes the functionality of /f**, with the
> additional analysis of physical disk errors.

This means that `chkdsk /r` does the sector-checking in addition
to all the other checks that it does, which includes checking the
metadata of all the folders and files on the disk.

This means that the more files and folders on the disk, the more
work chkdsk will do.

Comment: So if my main reason here is to check for bad sectors, running chdsk /r on an empty disk is fine?

Comment: Yes - on an empty disk the metadata check part will basically take very little time.

Answer (score 0):

CHKDSK has to check files for errors and cross-linking.

Yes, it will take much longer to check on a disk with a lot of data, than empty (not much to do to look at empty disk space).

CHKDSK can also check hardware health but you may need to specify the /f parameter and that will take time as well.

Please see:   [Check Disk](https://www.cdw.com/content/cdw/en/articles/hardware/how-to-check-hard-drive-health.html#:%7E:text=Windows%20Chkdsk,do%20so%20as%20an%20administrator.)

There are some differences between CHKDSK /r and /f

[chkdks r and f](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/chkdsk-f-or-r.html)

Comment: /r automatically invokes /f